# Calculating numbers and doing functions on related table and display it using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have a neighborhood layer and it have a relation with a table of transactions that have been made inside that neighborhood.
I'm working on ArcGis online and web app builder.

What I want is when the user click on a neighborhood, the user will see options to chose what type of indicators he wants like Avg,max,min and he has the ability to apply any of these function on any column he wants.

For example :

Sum of all `transaction_price` or avg in this neighborhood

`transaction_price` is a column in transaction table .

I tried Related Table Charts widget but it can't do any function on any column.

Simply I want to use Charts widget but with related table ,How ? or any widget to do this ?

Is there a widget to do something like this on related tables?

Comment: How did you load the neighborhood layer into arcgis online (zipped shapefile, layer package, arcgis server feature service)?

Comment: @artwork21 I share it as service via ArcMap desktop and publish it to my organization after creating the relationship class

Comment: Typically field drop downs are defined by database domain pick lists that are assigned to a given field (initially setup in ArcGIS Desktop), I imagine this applies for layers loaded into web app builder too.

Comment: @artwork21 How ?

Comment: see link for general reference http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-attribute-domains.htm

Comment: @artwork21 This is not helping and it's not what I asked for , but thanks